# Gnome-shell VNC remote desktop connection, ugly blue colors

Tags: gnome, vnc, remmina

When I connect to my remote gnome desktop, using remmina, during session when screen refreshes, is has ugly blue colors.

You can see this behaviour in this video:

http://youtu.be/uK9M532psAk

Is it possible to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

*Try changing the colour depth and quality settings.*[image]